# dojo:How to format the date type in grid

Tags: date, dojo, grid, format

here is my code. as a result, it can't format any date according to the datePattern.

thank you for any help in advance

```javascript
<script type="text/javascript">

var store = new dojo.data.ObjectStore({objectStore:new dojo.store.Memory({data:[{MyDate:new Date(2011,1,1)},{MyDate:new Date(2011,1,1)}]})});
dojo.addOnLoad(function()
{
var layout=
[
    {field:"MyDate",datatype:"date",dataTypeArgs:{datePattern:"yyyy"}}
];

Grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid(
{
    id:"Grid",
    selectable:true,
    store: store,
    structure: layout,

});
Grid.placeAt("GridLayer");
Grid.startup();
});

</script>

<div id="GridLayer" style="width:98%;height:600px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docs are being improved for this.  Look at the [current staging docs for DataGrid](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/grid/DataGrid) near the bottom where it says "See Also" the link for "Demos on how to display and edit date value in grid cells"

Comment: According to your document, I replace the "dataTypeArgs" width "formatter" and take effect.